# Generate a report per company, broken down by user

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that is used by different organisations. Each organisation has 3 different accounts that it's users use to login (for example admin, user, peasant).

What is best method, using Google Analytics, of creating individual reports for each organisation, broken down by users e.g. Organisation Acme report would include page views separated by admins, users and peasants?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `User` scoped custom dimension called, for example, `accountType`, that gets set when the user logs in. Then you can create custom segments that breaks down your site usage based on that custom dimension.